# When Last Modifed should be generated in webserver?

Tags: c, caching, tcp, webserver

I am making webserver in C and I encountered a question: when Last-Modified header should be generated? More specifically, when I should call stat() to check file size/date/inode and generate the header? Each GET request, add watcher to filesystem, etc?

Comment: Look at the standard: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html  (search for "last-modified")

Comment: I looked it, but it doesn't say when specifically it should be requested from FS for example.

Comment: Considering in regards to Last-Modified the standard says "For files, it may be just the file system last-modified time. "  And since you are talking about a file in the filesystem, then it would by "the file system last-modified time."... in EACH request... i.e. GET and HEAD, and if you are supporting Webdav extensions to HTTP 1.1, then also PROPFIND, etc.  Additionally, Apache's default_handler() sets it after successfully opening the file when handling a GET.

Comment: Won't it reduce server perfomance to check stat() EACH request?

Comment: When performing a GET, you are "opening, and reading" the resource (i.e. file)... that is more I/O than performing a simple "stat()".  In my opinion, stat() isn't a performance issue... The standard says "HTTP/1.1 servers SHOULD send Last-Modified whenever feasible. "... so, how else will you obtain that information that is both current and less I/O..?